# Drupal 7 custom form submit handler is not being called

Tags: forms

I am trying to write a custom handler for one of the Drupal 7 forms:

```
function mymodule_formid_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

 array_unshift($form['#submit'], 'mymodule_formid_submit');

}

function mymodule_formid_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function () { alert("Hello!"); });', 'inline');
    return
}
```

But it is not accessing the handler. Alter method *is* being called and printing 'mymodule_formid_submit' in the #submit array.

Maybe I am missing something, but exiting answers on Stack Overflow related to custom handlers are not helping in my case.

Comment: Difficult to tell here but you know that its hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().

Comment: First comment for ten points:  You're not closing your last line (`return` should be `return;`).

Comment: Why use JavaScript to check it? drupal_set_message('hello'), and you will see 'hello' in a drupal message(not popup) and it works regardless of page redirects.

Comment: I have checked it with plain drupal_set_message and my actual use case is to add a custom js file.

Answer (score 6):

I had this same problem trying to edit commerce_product form. For some reason the submit handlers are registered under actual submit button and custom handlers added to the #submit -element weren't registered.

```
$form['#submit'][] = 'my_custom_handler';
$form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'my_custom_handler';
```

So when I added that second line to register my custom handler to button and atleast it works.

Comment: +1 Thank you @Janne - I found this to work with my generic form submit handler. By generic I mean that on the basis of my success with it, I would therefore think that this solution should work for general Drupal hook form submit handlers. The crucial thing seems to be your advice to add the second line - which makes it work.

Answer (score 4):

In the **mymodule_form_alter()** function (replace mymodule with your module's name), override the **#submit** property of the form your want to handle.

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
switch($form_id){
    case 'some_form_id':
      // some code to handle the form. 
       $form['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_mysubmit_handler';
     break;
  }
}
```

Either you have to user **hook_form_alter()** or **hook_form_FORMID_alter()** function.
So you should write mymodule_form_formid_alter() function.

Comment: its not working $form['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_mysubmit_handler';

Comment: have you check that form_alter() is being called ?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it accessing your handler.
BUT, after it, Drupal makes internal redirect to avoid some problems with page refreshing. On the redirected page your handler will not be called (it has been called already), and your JS will not be added to the page.