# download file on form submission

Tags: 7, forms

I have created a form which has only a submit button. In the submit function I am generating csv file and saving it to the files folder using `fputcsv` function.

But Now I need extra functionality of submit. After saving the file it should download the file also.

How to do this? Any one have some idea about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attach a form submit handler (code here: [Drupal 7 custom form submit handler is not being called](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/45953/drupal-7-custom-form-submit-handler-not-working)).

Then set the file url to $form_state['redirect'].

The file download should begin when submitted.

Answer (score 3):

In Drupal 8 to have the file download rather than redirect to it you can use:

```
$uri = $file->getFileUri();
  $headers = array(
    'Content-Type'     => $file->getMimeType(),
    'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment;filename="'.$file->getFilename().'"'
  );
  $form_state->setResponse(new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse($uri, 200, $headers, true));
```

Answer (score 1):

In the following code I am downloading file as attachment created with phpExcel.
It may help someone.

```
function dn_preorder_form_submit($form,&$form_state){   
                $excel = new PHPExcel();
                $excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
                $excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1',"TEST");

                header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
                header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="var.xlsx"');
                header("Pragma: no-cache");
                header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
                header("Cache-Control: nmax-age=0");

                $file = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($excel,'Excel2007');

                $file->save('php://output');
                exit();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a file stream, and Drupal specific

```
$filename = "report.csv";
$stream = "public://";
$uri = $stream . $filename; // Better to add a subfolder per context

$headers = [
  'Content-Type' => 'text/csv',
  'Content-Description' => 'File Download',
  'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"'
];

$rfh = fopen($uri, 'w');

fputcsv($rfh, ['ID', 'Mail', 'Name']);
fputcsv($rfh, ['1', 'xyz@do-re-mi.com', 'Jaffe Joffer']);

fclose($rfh);

$form_state->setResponse(new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse($uri, 200, $headers, true));
```